# How should I upload my .vcf contacts to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, contacts

I have configured Thunderbird. Now I want to import my .vcf contact file to Thunderbird. What should I do to import it?

Answer (score 0):

This you should search in the Thunderbird documentation

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Help_Documentation:Migrating_to_Mozilla_Thunderbird

.